# Size classes constraint not working

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have 2 view in viewController,

BlueView and GreenView,

GreenView is BlueView subview.

[image]

**BlueView constraints:**

- Trailing Space to: Superview(ViewController.view)
- Leading Space to: Superview(ViewController.view)
- BottomSpace to: Superview(ViewController.view)
- Top Space to: Superview(ViewController.view)

**GreenView constraints:**

- Trailing Space to: Superview(BlueView)
- Leading Space to: Superview (BlueView)
- Bottom Space to: Superview (BlueView)
- Proportional Hight to View (ViewController.view)
  (ViewController.view.height *0.5)

It work for universal layout.

But in size classes(wC hR), not working.

[image]

GreenView hight constraint not active

- Proportional Hight to View (ViewController.view)

Universal layout, works fine:
[image]

Size classes(wC hR), not working as I expected:

[image]

Use IBoutlet active this constraint

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.greenViewHeightConstraint.active = YES;
}
```

It work!?

[image]

This constraint in size classes is illegal?

But in viewDidAppear is legal?

Any idea?

Comment: not sure exactly what you do in xib but size classes are active only after viewDidLayoutSubViews() not in viewDidLoad() or viewWillAppear()

Comment: What are you trying to change between size classes?